# Use data from 2 tables but no need to join?

Tags: sql

I have a table A with a column of some years and a table B with 2 columns of `startyear` & `endyear`.
I need to check whether years in A are in periods of B and count the appearance frequency of each period. So, I wrote:

```
SELECT B.periodname,count(A.id)
FROM A, B
WHERE A.year >= B.startyear AND A.year < B.endyear
GROUP BY B.periodname
```

Is this a valid query? Do I need to join A on B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your method is valid, it is more commonly written using `JOIN`:

```
ELECT B.periodname, COUNT(A.id)
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON A.year >= B.startyear AND A.year < B.endyear
GROUP BY B.periodname
```

Comment: Thanks! I've always thought when using join I must indicate the keys to connect 2 tables. So here the "year in period" relationship can also be used as the join condition?

Comment: @vivlumn . . . Any boolean expression can be used.  Equality usually has better performance, though.